# MongoDB Insert Field to all documents in a collection

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to add a new field into all documents in an existing collection.

Database name = test
Collection name = teams

```
test.teams.update({
}
,
{
    $set: {
        "isGolden": false
    }
}
,
false,
true)
```

When I am trying it with MongoChef, it is giving me the following error:
[image]

What is wrong with this?
Thanks

Comment: Shouldn't that be `use test; db.teams.update({}, {$set: {isGolden: false}}, false, true);`?

Comment: my database name is test  but I tried that version too but it is not working.

Comment: You need to run that full command in the MongoChef IntelliShell, not whatever query JSON editor you're in there. But it does need to be `db.teams.update` like chridam says, not `test.teams.update`.

Answer (score 28):

If you want to update all the documents, use something like this:

```
db.teams.update({}, {$set: {isGolden: false}}, {multi: true});
```

your are selecting all, setting the field `isGolden` to false and making this update in all documents using multi: true

Comment: it says "Expecting an opening '{' at line 1, col 2"

This is what I get all the time with different variants

Comment: This is the only query you are not being able to execute?
I tested it on mongo shell 3.0.7 on arch linux and it works fine

Comment: Thanks guys I have done that with MongoChef Advanced-> Update Dialogue. I selected all documents in the collection and add the field. Now it worked.

Comment: I get the following error when I try to invoke this script: 2020-07-13 11:41:14] java.lang.Exception: TypeError: invokeMember (updateMany) on JavaObject[com.mongodb.mongosh.service.JavaServiceProvider@32286f7d (com.mongodb.mongosh.service.JavaServiceProvider)] failed due to: Arity error - expected: 6 actual: 5
[2020-07-13 11:41:14] TypeError: invokeMember (updateMany) on JavaObject[com.mongodb.mongosh.service.JavaServiceProvider@32286f7d (com.mongodb.mongosh.service.JavaServiceProvider)] failed due to: Arity error - expected: 6 actual: 5
 - The question is WHY? Nobody can help me

Answer (score 6):

With MongoDB 3.2 or higher version, you can do

```
db.teams.updateMany({}, {$set: {isGolden: false}});
```

Here's the doc for updateMany function [db.collection.updateMany()](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/method/db.collection.updateMany/)

Answer (score 3):

With Studio 3T you were writing queries in JSON mode in which it wants JSON data but you are not writing JSON Query. You must go to InteliShell mode in which your query will execute in format that you were writing.

[image: Studio 3T InteliShell]